# Is there a method lcov in ignoring some directories from the report

Tags: linux, lcov

I have the line `lcov -c -i -d . -o cov_init.info`which captures the coverage data from an initial point of zero from a directory but I want it to ignore some directories. I was thinking of using a conditional statement but I'm new to using linux and not sure on how to write the conditional statement regarding the directories that I don't want lcov to display

Comment: Have you tried something like `iconv .... | grep -E -v '/path1/to/exclude|/path2/to/exclude|/path3/to/exclude|....'` ? Get 1 dir to work, then add more, separated by `|` (the `grep` "OR"` operator). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter can you give me more detail on the syntax. For instance why is written like /path1/to/exclude

Comment: `/path1/to/exclude`, etc are strictly a place holders. You'll have to review your `iconv` output, decide which directories you want to exclude, and then assemble a list like `/path1/...|/path2/...|....` The `-v` option means "skip lines that contain the search targets" (a negative grep, if you like). You might need to experiment with a small file to understand how regular grep works, then `grep -v srchTarg`, and then `grep -E -v 'excludeTarg1|excludeTarg2|...`. Then apply that knowledge to your `iconv` output. Good luck.

Comment: And see this answer for a good intro to basic (non `-v`) greps : http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37316/6122 . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude all external sources (e.g., system/standard libraries) from your coverage reports, use the `--no-external` option in the LCOV command, e.g.:

```
lcov -c -i -d . --no-external -o cov_init.info
```

If you want to be more specific, use the `--remove` option to explicitly specify what to remove from your tracefile.  The syntax is `lcov --remove tracefile pattern1 [pattern2...] -o new_tracefile`, e.g.:

```
lcov --remove cov_init.info "/path1/to/exclude*" "/local/package/lib/*" -o cov_init2.info
```

Note that *pattern* is interpreted as shell pattern/wildcard, not as regex.